# Merge non contiguous partitions

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

Bbought a new laptop, but it came with the following partitioning scheme (an unholy mess, IMHO):

[image]

I want to merge OS(C:) and DATA(F:) with out damaging the rest. Is this possible?

Comment: You would have to delete the 350MB partition in the middle. I'm not sure what function it serves on your computer.